# Position & center each li element based on position and width of each different element

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have an inline-block row of `<div>`s spaced out across the page inside a wrapper. Below that I have a list of absolute-positioned `<li>`s that I'd like to center under each of their corresponding `<div>`s.

So, I'm trying to loop through the list of `<li>`s, positioning them based on the position of the corresponding `<div>`, and centering each `<li>` below that `<div>` based on the `<div>`s width.

Does that make sense?

This is what I have, but my javascript/jquery knowledge is coming up short, I'm afraid:

```
// Loop over each li
$( ".group-labels li" ).each(function() {
    var id = $(this).data('bind');
    var theXPosition = $("#" + id).position.left;
    var theWidth = $("#" + id).innerWidth;  

    // Add margin-left to the li equivalent to .group's theXPosition
    $(this).css("margin-left") = theXPosition;

    // Centering <li>s with text-align: center in css and width of corresponding div set here
    $(this).css("width") = theWidth;

});
```

I'm sure there's plenty more that needs fixing, but I especially can't figure out how to incorporate the second loop to retrieve each ".spectrum-group" position and innerWidth.

Any pointers in the right direction is much appreciated.

EDIT -> adding HTML:

```
        <div class="spectrum-wrap">
            <div class="spectrum">
                <div class="spectrum-group" id="spectrum-group1">
                    <span id="student1"></span>
                    <span id="student2"></span>
                    <span id="student3"></span>
                </div>
                <div class="spectrum-group" id="spectrum-group2">
                    <span id="student4"></span>
                    <span id="student5"></span>
                    <span id="student6"></span>
                    <span id="student7"></span>
                    <span id="student8"></span>
                    <span id="student9"></span>
                    <span id="student10"></span>
                    <span id="student11"></span>
                </div>
                <div class="spectrum-group" id="spectrum-group3">
                    <span id="student12"></span>
                    <span id="student13"></span>
                    <span id="student14"></span>
                    <span id="student15"></span>
                </div>
                <div class="spectrum-group" id="spectrum-group4">
                    <span id="student16"></span>
                    <span id="student16"></span>
                </div>
                <div class="spectrum-group" id="spectrum-group5">
                    <span id="student17"></span>
                    <span id="student17"></span>
                </div>
            </div><!-- .spectrum end -->
            <div class="spectrum-group-labels">
                <ul class="group-labels">
                    <li data-bind="spectrum-group1"><a href="#group1">Group 1</a></li>
                    <li data-bind="spectrum-group2"><a href="#group2">Group 2</a></li>
                    <li data-bind="spectrum-group3"><a href="#group3">Group 3</a></li>
                    <li data-bind="spectrum-group4"><a href="#group4">Group 4</a></li>
                    <li data-bind="spectrum-group5"><a href="#group5">Group 5</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Comment: add html please, u have many syntax errors (jquery)

Comment: I've just added it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need the `function` inside your loop and the element `this` needs to refer to the `li` element in your loop which won't work anymore if you wrap a function around it.

However the function is needed as parameter of your `.each()` as it is a callback function (executed for each `li` element).

**Update:**

If you want to adapt the position to the group element, I would recommend you to link both items by adding an attribute (e.g. a `dataset` attribute).

Add to each `li` element following attribute: `data-bind="ID"` where `ID` will be the `id` of your group container.

So the working code should be:

```
// Loop over each li
$( ".group-labels li" ).each(function() {
    var id = $(this).data('bind');
    var theXPosition = $("#" + id).position().left;
    var theWidth = $("#" + id).width();  

    // Add margin-left to the li equivalent to .group's theXPosition
    // And centering <li>s with text-align: center in css and width of corresponding div
    $(this).css({"left": theXPosition, "width": theWidth});

});
```

Comment: Great, that fixes my `.each` syntax(edited above), but the root of my question is the second loop for `theXPosition` and `theWidth`. Right now, I'm only getting a single value for those. I need to loop through each `.group` div, get their position/width, then pass that on to be used for the css of the `.labels li`.

Comment: @dmoz Can you add your HTML code including the list and `.group` elements? Would help to solve this.

Comment: Yes, I've just added it.

Comment: @dmoz I updated my post. You won't need a second loop if you bind your `li` elements with the group id by using the `data-bind="ID"` attribute (and using the updated JavaScript code).

Comment: I think that might work, but it might be backwards in your answer..? I need to change the position of `<li>` elements based on `theXPosition` of the `.spectrum-group`s, so do I need to add `dataset` to the `.spectrum-group` divs with the corresponding `<li>` IDs instead so that the `theXPosition` variable is filled with the position of that div?

Comment: @dmoz If you link the correct group to your `li` by adding the `id` of your group as the value of the `data-bind` attribute, it will take the `.innerWidth` and `position.left` of that specific group. It is only about linking the HTML tags to each other with that attribute. If you link them in the wrong order, you might want to link them in the reverse order.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification and answer! So I edited my code above with what I have from your answer, and it looks like it should do what you're saying, but it's not.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/130556/discussion-between-wigi-and-dmoz).

Answer (score 0):

Well, for starters, anything positioned absolutely only respects `margin-left` if it also uses the `left` positioning property.

And in your code above, aren't you going to get the same value for `theXPosition` each time through the loop?  So, even if the margin-left is working on those items, you are positioning each of them at the same place.

jQuery is pretty flexible, but I though the only valid argument to .each() is a callback function. But you have unclosed variable declarations (`theXPosition`, `theWidth`), followed by a callback function. Just a typo?

Answer (score 0):

if i understood correctly

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  var groups = $(".spectrum-group");
  
  $( ".group-labels li" ).each(function(index, el) {
    var group = groups.eq(index),
        pos = group.offset().left,
        width = group.outerWidth();
    //console.log(' ',index,'\t',pos, '\t',width);

    $(el).css({"margin-left": pos, "width": width});
  });
});
```

```css
.spectrum{width: 100%;}
.spectrum-group{float: left; width: 20%;}
.spectrum-group > span{display: block; text-align: center;}
.spectrum-group:nth-of-type(even){background-color: #eee;}
.group-labels{padding-left: 0; width: 100%; list-style-type: none;}
.group-labels > li{text-align: center;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="spectrum-wrap">
            <div class="spectrum">
                <div class="spectrum-group" id="spectrum-group1">
                    <span id="student1">1</span>
                    <span id="student2">2</span>
                    <span id="student3">3</span>
                </div>
                <div class="spectrum-group" id="spectrum-group2">
                    <span id="student4">4</span>
                    <span id="student5">5</span>
                    <span id="student6">6</span>
                    <span id="student7">7</span>
                    <span id="student8">8</span>
                    <span id="student9">9</span>
                    <span id="student10">10</span>
                    <span id="student11">11</span>
                </div>
                <div class="spectrum-group" id="spectrum-group3">
                    <span id="student12">12</span>
                    <span id="student13">13</span>
                    <span id="student14">14</span>
                    <span id="student15">15</span>
                </div>
                <div class="spectrum-group" id="spectrum-group4">
                    <span id="student16">16</span>
                    <span id="student16">16</span>
                </div>
                <div class="spectrum-group" id="spectrum-group5">
                    <span id="student17">17</span>
                    <span id="student17">17</span>
                </div>
            </div><!-- .spectrum end -->
            <div class="spectrum-group-labels">
                <ul class="group-labels">
                    <li><a href="#group1">Group 1</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#group2">Group 2</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#group3">Group 3</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#group4">Group 4</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#group5">Group 5</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
```